# Add and Edit in same component in react

Tags: react-redux, react-hooks

if url is shipping/1245abcde, the form should load with the data comes from dispatch(getOrderDetails(orderId)). It does works fine when loading for first time but when I click refresh in the browser, it shows error at line: setAddress

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'shippingAddress' of undefined
```

Here, I cannot call useSelector inside the useEffect. Is there anyway to get orderDetails state inside the useEffect().

Below is the ShippingScreen components

```
const ShippingScreen = ({ history, match }) => {
  const orderId = match.params.orderId

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart)
  const { shippingAddress } = cart

  const [address, setAddress] = useState(shippingAddress.address)
  const [city, setCity] = useState(shippingAddress.city)
  const [postalCode, setPostalCode] = useState(shippingAddress.postalCode)
  const [country, setCountry] = useState(shippingAddress.country)

  const orderDetails = useSelector((state) => state.orderDetails)
  const { order } = orderDetails

  useEffect(() => {
    if (orderId) {
      dispatch(getOrderDetails(orderId))
      setAddress(order.shippingAddress.address)
      setCity(order.shippingAddress.city)
      setPostalCode(order.shippingAddress.postalCode)
      setCountry(order.shippingAddress.country)
    }
  }, [orderId])
```

Comment: How is `state.cart` defined?  Seems like thats not there when you try to destructure it.

Comment: state.cart comes from initialState which is assigned with localstorage value. It is defined in store.js i.e. const initialState = {
  cart: {
    cartItems: cartItemsFromStorage,

Comment: You have to check if data is loaded then do your thing. Ex: if you dispatch getOrderDetails. Then you have to check if data loaded then set to your states. Otherwise when it get late error will return.